# Square heatmap in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, heatmap, matlab-figure, image-scaling

I am using the consensusPlot.m function from [Lucas G. S. Jeub's HierarchicalConsensus MATLAB package](https://github.com/LJeub/HierarchicalConsensus) to create a heatmap with dendrogram on the right. I input a square matrix `C` and want the heatmap to be square. However, consensusPlot.m function by default returns a rectangular heatmap.

Here is the [sample data and modified consensusPlot.m together with dependend functions](https://github.com/Patricklv/Square-heatmap-MATLAB). Below is the code:

```
% Load data
ScTree = load('ScTree.mat');
Sc = ScTree.Sc;
Tree = ScTree.Tree;
C = load('C.mat');
C = C.C;

% Draw heatmap
consensusPlot(C, Sc, Tree);
set(gcf, 'PaperSize', [6 6]);
print(gcf, '-dpdf', 'Fig.pdf');
```

I looked into consensusPlot.m function and found the following most relevant code snippet for creating heatmap:

```
parseArgs=inputParser();
addParameter(parseArgs,'GroundTruth',[]);
addParameter(parseArgs,'Labels',{});
addParameter(parseArgs,'LabelFont',6);
addParameter(parseArgs,'ImageRescale',1);
parse(parseArgs,varargin{:});
Sgtruth=parseArgs.Results.GroundTruth;
labels=parseArgs.Results.Labels;
ylabelfont=parseArgs.Results.LabelFont;
imrescale=parseArgs.Results.ImageRescale;
clf()
ax_C_int=axes('position',[0.1,0.1,0.7,0.8]);
ax_H_int=axes('position',[0.8,0.1,0.1,0.8]);

N=length(C);
ylims=[0.5+0.5*1/imrescale,N+0.5-0.5*1/imrescale];
s_int=treeSort(C,Sc,Tree);
imagesc(ax_C_int,ylims,ylims, imresize(C(s_int,s_int),imrescale,'nearest'));
if ~isempty(labels)
    set(ax_C_int,'ytick',1:N,'yticklabel',labels(s_int),...
        'xtick',1:N,'xticklabel',labels(s_int),'xticklabelrotation',90,...
        'ticklabelinterpreter','None','fontsize',ylabelfont)
end
```

The heatmap is on the left and dendrogram is on the right of the final image. The default width of the heatmap is 0.7 and default height is 0.8. When I set `ax_C_int=axes('position',[0.1,0.1,0.7,0.7]);`, the heatmap becomes even more enlongated. I am wondering how should I modify the original code to create a square heatmap.

I have two additional requirement:

1. There should be no space between the heatmap and the dendrogram;
2. I modified the code to add color bar below the heatmap, which is of equal width to the heatmap. I want to ensure that when the heatmap becomes square, the color bar remains of equal width to the heatmap.